# Samsung SmartTV PNACL SDK 5.1 Works in Emulator not on TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, google-nativeclient

Re gard my topic problem I have some basic questions about PNACL

1. Does PNACL is supported by all samsung SmartTV?

2.If I use pepper 31 will my application work on older TV's?

And now the main problem

I've compiled application in C (basic helloworld from SDK 5.1 + some additional code of mine), for x86 architecture and it works  both in emulator and chrome.
Then I recompiled it for Samsung Smart TV (arm) (I have 2013 series). 
Aplication starts on TV, but PNACL module dont dispalay any result, the js onload callback of div containing module is called but nothing else.
Does my tv support PNACL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the 2013 series, you will need an older version of the pepper SDK (31 wont work).

In [this link](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/7e2b7fa90012098b?currentPage=1&searchText=&selectcontents=1&forumID=2f2dc36156f707cb&sorting_target=CreateDate&sorting_type=desc) you can download the pepper 25 SDK 
(for windows). Otherwise, you will have to get the SDK source code from Git and rebuild it. The native_client_sdk is part of the chromium project and can be found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/native_client_sdk).

Answer (score 4):

2013 and 2014 models support PNACL.

- 2013 models: only support up to pepper29
- 2014 models: only support up to pepper33.

I hope this information help you.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, tanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the older releases of nacl here http://gsdview.appspot.com/nativeclient-mirror/nacl/nacl_sdk/.